# openstack identity api get response error code

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js, openstack

im intern student. I have a question .

Im working to bug/fix on an Openstack cloud , Javascript and nodejs web app. Now im fixing toastr.error messages and then translate message's language.

How can i get openstack-identity-api response error code ? I have some documents about error code's reason like this.

> Code  Reason
>
> 204 - No Content  The server has fulfilled the request.
>
> Error¶
>
> Code  Reason 400 - Bad Request    Some content in the request was invalid
>
> 401 - Unauthorized    User must authenticate before making a request.
>
> 403 - Forbidden   Policy does not allow current user to do this
>   operation.
>
> 404 - Not Found   The requested resource could not be found.
>
> 409 - Conflict    This operation conflicted with another operation on
>   this resource.

`https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/identity/v3/?expanded=change-password-for-user-detail`

Example :

```
if(resp.error === 401){
     toastr.error("Authentication failure. Please contact the system administrator.");}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please explain your ask here? The Openstack API document you have referred clearly shows the response codes and what might be the cause for each error code. What additional info you would require?